# How to reference a requirements.txt in the pyproject.toml of a setuptools project?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pyproject.toml

I'm trying to migrate a *setuptools*-based project from the legacy `setup.py` towards modern `pyproject.toml` configuration.

At the same time I want to keep well established workflows based on `pip-compile`, i.e., a `requirements.in` that gets compiled to a `requirements.txt` (for end-user / non-library projects of course). This has important benefits as a result of the full transparency:

- 100% reproducible installs due to pinning the full transitive closure of dependencies.
- better understanding of dependency conflicts in the transitive closure of dependencies.

For this reason I don't want to maintain the dependencies directly inside the `pyproject.toml` via a `dependencies = []` list, but rather externally in the `pip-compiled` managed `requirements.txt`.

This makes me wonder: Is there a way to reference a `requirements.txt` file in the `pyproject.toml` configuration, without having to fallback to a `setup.py` script?

Comment: This is a good question, but a bit upside-down in my opinion... We now have [PEP 621](https://peps.python.org/pep-0621/) that standardizes how (among other things) dependencies should be specified in `pyproject.toml`. So the question you should ask yourself should be: "how can I get `pip-compile` (and other packaging tools) to use the list of dependencies from the `pyproject.toml` as input". Indeed the standardized `pyproject.toml` should be the source of truth.

Comment: @sinoroc: That's mostly true for libraries, but for non-library / end-user / delivery projects it is good practice to fully pin the transitive closure, i.e., the dependencies referenced in the `pyproject.toml` should not be equivalent to the typical `requirements.in` but rather the fully compiled output. Of course, you can copy/paste the compiled output of pip-compile back into the `pyprojects.toml` but that makes an automated "bump dependency" process awkward. In such cases it is easier to separate the "machine generated" parts from the otherwise human-maintained `pyproject.toml` content.

Comment: I am not sure I understand... You want to pin the dependencies in the application's project metadata?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Use [dynamic metadata](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html#dynamic-metadata):

```ini
[project]
dynamic = ["dependencies"]
[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
dependencies = {file = ["requirements.txt"]}
```

Note that the referenced file will use a `requirements.txt`-*like* syntax; each line must conform to [PEP 508](https://peps.python.org/pep-0508/), so flags like `-r`, `-c`, and `-e` are not supported inside this `requirements.txt`.

Additionally:

> If you are using an old version of `setuptools`, you might need to ensure that all files referenced by the `file` directive are included in the `sdist` (you can do that via `MANIFEST.in` or using plugins such as `setuptools-scm`, please have a look on [sic] [Controlling files in the distribution](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/miscellaneous.html) for more information).
>
> *Changed in version 66.1.0*: Newer versions of `setuptools` will automatically add these files to the `sdist`.

If you want to use `optional-dependencies`, say, with a `requirements-dev.txt`, you will need to put an extra group, as follows (credit to Billbottom):

```ini
[project]
dynamic = ["dependencies", "optional-dependencies"]
[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
dependencies = {file = ["requirements.txt"]}
optional-dependencies = {dev = { file = ["requirements-dev.txt"] }}
```

However:

> Currently, when specifying `optional-dependencies` dynamically, all of the groups must be specified dynamically; one can not specify some of them statically and some of them dynamically.

Comment: Does not work for me.  It does not cause a failure during build or installation  but it does not install any requirements either! And to quote from your linked page: _Currently the following fields can be listed as dynamic: version, classifiers, description, entry-points, scripts, gui-scripts and readme._  Not a word about `dependencies`.

Comment: @dennis If you scroll down on that page, you'll see a table that lists "dependencies" as being in beta for dynamic metadata. What version of setuptools do you have?

Comment: @dennis Also note that "`pip`-specify syntaxes, e.g. `-c/-r/-e` flags, are not supported".

Comment: Any idea want to put for content-type? e.g. `readme = {file = ["README.md"], content-type = "text/markdown"}`

Comment: @RayBell You don't need to set `content-type`. That's only for the readme.

Comment: `python -m build` did not install dependencies from the `requirements` file. But `pip install  -e .` did for me.

Comment: @winterlight Sorry about that; You might want to check your setup, and if it looks right, you might want to file a bug report about that. Then again, it's possible that it isn't required to support dynamic metadata for dependencies, as it's in beta.

Comment: @pigrammer I think it is expected as the `build` documentation https://pypa-build.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ says "It is a simple build tool and does not perform any dependency management."

Comment: It builds but have the feeling that it would not install anything since the requirements.txt is not included in any of the built of the 2 files `.wheel` nor `.tar.gz`

Comment: @ramin Can you try installing it and seeing if it works?

Comment: my project is still on "testpypi" and it didnt install the requirements even when they were in the pyproject file... I suppose it checks in the same repo for the requirements...
I will check if there is a way to change the repo and make a test

Comment: @ramin See the recent edit, I added some information that might help

Comment: package installed... but no dependencies. I am using setuptools v 68.0.0

Comment: This comment is only for the optional dependencies: I'm on `setuptools` 68.0.0, and to get the optional dependencies to work I had to add a group property before listing the file(s). In my case, specifying the `requirements-dev.txt` file and associating it with a `dev` group worked with the following property in the `tool.setuptools.dynamic` table: `optional-dependencies = {dev = { file = ["requirements-dev.txt"] }}`

Comment: @Bilbottom do you mind if I edit that in?

Comment: @pigrammer feel free to! :)

Comment: @pigrammer I'm on setuptools 68.2.2 and I had to set `dynamic = ["dependencies","optional-dependencies"]` in `[project]` for this to work, otherwise i got warned that my package doesn't provide the extra optional dependancy name

Comment: @Osamoele yeah, that makes sense - forgot to put that in the code in the answer. I'll do it now.

Answer (score -2):

`pip-tools` can read the dependencies from `pyproject.toml`, just like it would from a `requirements.in`.
That's not the same as referencing the compiled dependencies in `requirements.txt`, but it is one step closer: you don't need `requirements.in` and you can distribute `requirements.txt`.

Like @sinoroc, I think it may be risky to "deliver" requirements with only pinned versions. It's sufficient that one similarly set up project is set up along with your project, and you're likely to get clashes.
Of course, you may be able to exclude that, or perhaps even want to exploit that nothing else is used along with your project. But that's a very specific use case.