Create python package and make it automatically install dependencies
I am creating a python package.
I have been using Pipenv to manage environments, and dependencies.
I would like to create the package and have dependencies installed when someone pip installs, or installs from the .whl
Say my Pipfile has:
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
numpy = "==1.26.4"
pandas = "==2.2.1"
pyproject-hooks = "==1.0.0"
python-dateutil = "==2.9.0.post0"
pytz = "==2024.1"
six = "==1.16.0"
tzdata = "==2024.1"
pytest = "*"

[dev-packages]
build = "==1.2.1"
packaging = "==24.0"
isort = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.11"

And I have a pyproject.toml file:
[project]
name = "MyPyProject"
version = "0.0.1"
dynamic = ["dependencies"]

[tools.setuptools.dynamic]
dependencies = {file = ["requirements.txt"]}

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61","wheel"]

The steps I have taken are to create the requirements.txt file from pipenv:
pipenv requirements > requirements.txt

but when I build using:
python -m build

the requirements in the requirements.txt file are not being installed when I install the produced .whl in a fresh environment.
Am I missing an obvious step here?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73600610/7976758 Try [tool.setuptools.dynamic] not [tools.setuptools.dynamic] Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpyproject.toml%5D+dynamic+dependencies
