How to generate pyproject.toml similar to pip freeze
How can I update/generate a pyproject.toml?
I used to be able to do pip freeze to generate a requirements.txt.
However, this isn't how its been done lately with stuff like poetry and what not, so like, is there something like this?:
pip freeze --generate-pyproject-toml
Related:

https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/pyproject-toml/#pyproject-toml-spec
PEP-517, PEP-518, PEP-621
Is requirements.txt still needed when using pyproject.toml?

I've tried all sorts of stuff, and looked on the internet for a couple hours.
I mean I could write a bash script and be done with it, but I was hoping there was some new feature I am unaware of.

You can read requirements.txt in pyproject.toml: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73600610/7976758

update i've add a pypi package for this
pip install fastapi
pip install pyproject-freeze
pypfreeze

old answer
I know this isn't a great answer, but you might be able to do something like this, I'm not sure there is an existing tool:
import importlib
import importlib.metadata
from tomlkit import dumps
from tomlkit import parse

def get_installed_packages():
    packages = {}
    for dist in importlib.metadata.distributions():
        name = dist.metadata["Name"]
        version = dist.version
        packages[name] = version
    return packages

def update_pyproject_toml(file_path):
    try:
        with open(file_path, "r") as f:
            pyproject_data = f.read()
        pyproject_data = parse(pyproject_data)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pyproject_data = {}

    # pyproject_data.setdefault("tool", {}).setdefault("poetry", {})
    pyproject_data["tool"]["poetry"]["dependencies"] = get_installed_packages()
    pyproject_data["tool"]["poetry"]["dev-dependencies"] = {}
    # pyproject_data.setdefault("build-system", {})
    # pyproject_data["build-system"]["requires"] = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
    # pyproject_data["build-system"]["build-backend"] = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
    # with open(file_path, "w") as file:
    print(dumps(pyproject_data))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_path = "pyproject.toml"
    update_pyproject_toml(file_path)



pyproject.toml and the output of pip freeze servers different use cases. So the answer to "How to generate pyproject.toml similar to pip freeze" must be "You cannot".
While within your pyproject.toml you declare dependencies the project directly depend on (either fixed versions or version range) the output of pip freeze contains all concrete packages installed the environment. So it includes dependencies of the dependencies as well.
Because you've tagged the post with python-poetry:
If you only ever install the project using Poetry there's not much you have to do. Poetry creates a poetry.lock on the first poetry install which contains information on which Poetry can recreate the environment with the exact versions of all dependencies. Using poetry add or poetry remove keeps this lock file in sync.
You can create a requirements.txt based on Poetry's lock file running poetry export -f requirements.txt -o requirements.txt

Thanks, I'll take a look at the suggestions. It's kinda a bummer if all i want to do is create/update a pyproject.toml from what I already have installed like pip freeze though, i don't see there being different uses cases given PEP-518/517, but who knows there's like N+1 standards around python packaging. And overall, its not really about poetry, but PEP-517 and PEP-518 tooling which when used makes sense.
